# React app throwing re-render issue with iframe upon navigation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, iframe, react-typescript

I'm working on a react chrome plugin to display an existing react app in sidepanel of chrome using an iframe.

Whenever I try to navigate to another page of the react app, it throws:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

(upon reloading the iframe, the page is displayed correctly).

**P.S.** This issue persists only when the navigation is done within the iframe and not in the react app.

This is the code for sidepanel.tsx from react plugin.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <iframe
        id="iframe"
        src={"http://react-app.com"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
const root = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(root)
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root)
```

Can you suggest some changes in sidepanel code that could fix the rendering issue?